# Entity framework 6 foreign key is not being updated on attach and save

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-update, entity-framework-6, foreign-key-relationship

I have a issue with entity framework 6 not updating the foreign key when I try to update a entity object. It works on insert (but then I have to set the state to Unchanged for not to reinsert a new entity in the foreign key table). I am using code first approach and generated the models myself. It's a web application so the entity objects gets detached, so I have to reattach them.

I've created a simplified example so it's easy to explain what my problem is. In this example I have a car object which has a one to many relation to make. I want to update a car and change what make it is and its name. The name is updated but not the foreign key value. How do I go ahead to get the foreign key to be updated too?

The code handeling the attaching

```
public void UpdateCars(Car car){
    var dbContext = new CarsDbContext(); //Inherits DbContext
    dbContext.Cars.Attach(car);
    dbContext.Entry(car).State = EntityState.Modified;
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

The car Entity

```
[Table("Car")]
public class Car
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public String Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Make Make { get; set; }
}

[Table("Make")]
public class Make
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

---

Edit:

I did a few more changes with help from comments (thanks guys!) and I made something work but it feels like I'm doing it the wrong way because the code is far from pretty. Here's what I did:

Modified the Car object to:

```
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public Guid Make_Id

    [ForeignKey("Make_Id")]
    public virtual Make Make { get; set; }
```

In my update

```
    var dbContext = new CarsDbContext(); //Inherits DbContext
    car.Make_Id = car.Make.Id;
    dbContext.Cars.Attach(car);
```

There surely must be a better practice around this when doing EF code first when working with detached entities?

Comment: Have you tried attaching and setting the state of the "Make" entity as well, i suspect that will do the trick.

Comment: Does your Car object really not have a property for the foreign key to Make.Id or did you leave that out for brevity?

Comment: @BenRobinson Thanks for the suggestion but sadly it doesn't do the trick. I've tried: dbContext.Makes.Attach(car.Make); dbContext.Entry(car.Make).State = EntityState.Modified; doesn't work

Comment: @RobEpstein Actually I did try adding the Foreign key annotation but it crashes, it would typical be: [ForeignKey("Make_ID")] above the Make property in Car

Comment: @ArneHB, that requires having a property declared on your Car object like `public Guid MakeId { get; set; }`

Comment: @RobEpstein I thought that EF should handle that if you made that FK property virtual?

Comment: The `virtual` keyword lets EF wire up lazy-loading and change tracking. That's all.

Comment: @RobEpstein Ok thanks! I think I got it to work now. It's not a pretty code. To car I added: public Guid Make_Id and above Make property I added [ForeignKey("Make_Id")]. In the update function I had to change it so its now: car.Make_Id = car.Make.Id. This feels wrong, and the code is not pretty and I must be doing something wrong?

Comment: If you have the mapping correct then setting the Make property will cause EF to update the Make_Id property automatically.

Comment: @RobEpstein Yeah that seems to be the issue that Make_Id does not get updated automatically, do you have any idea or suggestion how to fix this? The Make property gets its correct values and stuff from DB and when I try to save the new changed make do I get a error because the new Make.Id and Make_Id does not corespond (why I have to set Make_Id to Make.Id)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60887/discussion-between-rob-epstein-and-arne-hb).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up using graphdiff which solved all my problems. Also when my entities became more complex and it tried to attachs same entity several times. Here's a article to read about it: http://blog.brentmckendrick.com/introducing-graphdiff-for-entity-framework-code-first-allowing-automated-updates-of-a-graph-of-detached-entities/